# Converting a YOLOv8 Image Detection Model from .pt to .h5, .weights or .cfg Format

Tags: keras, pytorch, darknet, yolov8

How can I convert a trained YOLOv8 image detection model saved as .pt extension to either .h5, .weights or .cfg file format?

I want to know if is it possible to do it and if possible how?

Comment: I think than onnx format is the best portable format. Do you think about it?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the Steps to convert yolo.pt model into yolo.weights

1. **Clone YOLO Repository**: Clone the official YOLO repository, which includes the Darknet framework and conversion scripts:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet
   cd darknet
   ```
2. **Configure Darknet**: Make sure you have Darknet configured to build with CUDA and OpenCV support by editing the `Makefile` as needed. Refer to the Darknet documentation for instructions specific to your system.
3. **Convert PyTorch Model**: You can use a script like `export.py` from the YOLOv5 repository to convert the PyTorch model to the Darknet format. This script can be found in the YOLOv5 repository:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5
   cd yolov5
   python export.py --weights /path/to/your/yolov8.pt --img-size 640 --dynamic --simplify
   ```

   Replace `/path/to/your/yolov8.pt` with the path to your YOLOv8 PyTorch model. You can also adjust the `--img-size` parameter based on your requirements.
4. **Find the Converted Weights**: The script will create a `yolov8-exported.onnx` file in the yolov5 repository directory. You can then convert this ONNX file to Darknet format using the `onnx2darknet.py` script, which is also available in the YOLOv5 repository.

   ```bash
   python export.py --weights /path/to/your/yolov8-exported.onnx
   ```

   This command will create a `yolov8.weights` file, which is the Darknet format model.